# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Arduino breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  3          8
Users destroyed                                  72          0
Users deleted                                     7          0
Users contacted                                   7          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            36      1,491
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                0      1,003
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          8      2,175
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        874
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 0      4,185
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                0      6,622
Tags merged                                       1          0
Revisions redacted                                1          0
Questions unprotected                             0          1
Questions reopened                               16         26
Questions protected                               1         35
Questions migrated                               37          0
Questions merged                                  5          0
Questions flagged⁴                                6        719
Questions closed                                511      1,488
Question flags handled⁴                         142        583
Posts unlocked                                    0         11
Posts undeleted                                   4         70
Posts locked                                      3        169
Posts deleted⁵                                  594      2,640
Posts bumped                                      0      5,281
Comments undeleted                                1          0
Comments flagged                                  0        597
Comments deleted⁶                             1,192      2,116
Comment flags handled                           175        422
Answers flagged                                   2      2,130
Answer flags handled                          1,582        550
All comments on a post moved to chat             32          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: One may ask: "Why do we even need moderators?". Well, the answer is simple: [people need someone to complain to](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/significant-results/201706/the-three-types-complaining).  Without someone to complain to they will just explode, and that would get messy.